# How to check if a particular overloaded function exists, using the decltype or declval

Tags: c++, c++17

I wrote the following code, here as msg_hdr() function has 2 overloads, which makes decltype unusable.
Instead of decltype, I have also tried `invoke_result_t` as well as `result_of_t`, but nothing seems to work.

What changes should I make in the code to make it work.

```
struct Header
{
    int i;
    int j;
};

struct Data
{    
    Header& msg_hdr()
    {
        return this->_msg_hdr;
    }
    
    const Header& msg_hdr() const
    {
        return this->_msg_hdr;
    }
    
    private:
        Header _msg_hdr;
        int k;
};

template<typename, typename = void>
constexpr bool has_msg_hdr = false;

template<typename St>
constexpr bool has_msg_hdr<St, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<decltype(St::msg_hdr), Header>>> = true;

template<typename St>
constexpr void check(St s)
{
    if constexpr(has_msg_hdr<std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<St>>>)
    {
        std::cout << "has msg_header \n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "no msg_header \n";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    Data d;    
    check(d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I got the same result ("no msg_header") even after removing one of the overloads of `msg_hdr()` (and after fixing the presumed typo). So it appears that having two overloads is a red herring. You might want to remove that from your question so you can better focus on the real issue.

Comment: The question you should be asking is not whether a function with some signature exists. Your code is not going to note the existence of a function; it's going to *call that function* with some kind of arguments. *That* is the thing whose validity needs to be verified: can this function be called with these arguments.

Comment: @JaMiT Corrected the typo. There is some external API, which is generating code in this way i.e. similar overloads. Actually I want to check that the private variable _msg_hdr exists. Overloads are generated in this way for every private variable by the API. But being private, I am not able to check it directly.

Comment: @virus00x OK, so you are stuck with overloads in your real code. Are you suggesting the the presence of the overloads should make the task easier? I see it as an unnecessary complication. A usual procedure is first to come up with a check that works in at least one case, then second, add restrictions and complications. Keep it simple to start. `struct Data { Header& msg_hdr(); };` is simple (probably no definition of the member function will be required for this check) -- can you detect this member function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use this trick to detect particular overload function.

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
class has_msg_hdr
{
    template <typename C,
              typename = decltype( std::declval<C>().msg_hdr(std::declval<Args>()...) )>
    static std::true_type test(int);
    template <typename C>
    static std::false_type test(...);

public:
    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test<T>(0))::value;
};
```

Test code.

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_msg_hdr<Data>::value << " " 
        << has_msg_hdr<Data,int>::value << std::endl;
```